# Equivalent ipfw config for firewalld

Tags: freebsd, ipfw, firewall-cmd

On a system managed by firewalld it is possible to redirect incoming traffic on 443 to 8443 so the process listening doesn't have to run as root to bind to 443 which requires root.

```
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=443:proto=tcp:toport=8443
```

I attempted to use

```
00011 fwd 127.0.0.1,8443 tcp from any to me 443
```

but it didn't work.

What is the IPFW equivalent of this firewall-cmd command?